# Change UIButton textlabel color by touching the button Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I read some articles but didn't find a solution that solved my problem. Currently im building an iOS app in Swift 3. I placed a UIButton called registerButton into my view. If someone touches the button a new ViewController shall appear(newController). Beside that the color of the registerButton.textlabel.setColor() should be changed when a user touches the button and hold it pressed ? The presentation of the newController works but not the change color of the textLabel. Im changing the color of the registerButton in the Registration function. Has someone an idea ?  Thanks

```
var registerButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system) 
    button.setTitle("Registration", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(registration), for: .touchUpInside) // Action
    return button
}()

   func registration(){

    let color = UIColor(r: 255, g: 0, b: 102)// red
    registerButton.setTitleColor(color, for: .highlighted)
    let newController = ViewController()

    present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }
```

[Button normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoFKo.png)

[Button pressed no red text label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqxq0.png)

Comment: you want to change the text Color of the button text when the button is pressed. Right??

Comment: @Md. Ibrahim Hassan Exactly! I want to change the color of the button when it is pressed. If I use the state .touchDown ( mentioned by @dfd)  it is not possible to keep the button pressed. Tthe new ViewController appears immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var registerButton: UIButton = {
let button = UIButton(type: .system) 
button.setTitle("Registration", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(colorChange), for: .touchDown)
button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .highlighted)
// Action
return button
}()
```

This should work just fine

Comment: Thank you that worked. The problem was that I changed the color in the registration function. Now I change the color in the stored property  registerButton!

Answer (score -2):

Try to change the color for the state **Focused** when you are creating the button, not when pressed.

```
     var registerButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system) 
    button.setTitle("Registration", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .focused)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(registration), for: .touchUpInside) // Action
    return button
}()
```

Comment: Nothing to do with `focused`

Comment: But when creating the button?